# Chef - Clone a specific tag from GitLab

Tags: git, svn, version-control, chef-infra, gitlab

I have this snippet where I should clone a repo from git:

```
git "somerepo" do
  action :sync
  destination "/var/"
  repository "http://#{node["somerepo"][:git_user]}:#{node["somerepo"][:git_pass]}@#{node["somerepo"][:git_host]}/#{node["somerepo"][:git_owner]}/somerepo.git"
  revision "#{node["somerepo"][:git_revision]}"
  user "root"
  group "root"
end
```

I have these several tags in a GitLab repo named like:
12022015
01052016
**02042016**

I want tags/02042016 to be cloned/checked out just how I set the settings in SVN. Please help. I kinda searched StackOverflow and I wish I am just overlooking a previous question like this. And if this is not possible, kindly advise so. :) Thank you.

Comment: Enter the tag as parameter to `revision`?

Comment: @StephenKing like `revision "tag/02042016"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html) suggests, you can supply tag names to the `revision` parameter.

```rb
git "apt-cookbook" do
  repository "https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/apt"
  revision "v2.9.2"
  action :sync
end
```

As this usage of the `revision` parameter is not bullet-proof (not sure, what happens, when a branch with the same name exists), you can also submit the complete [Git refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) for the tag, which is `refs/tags/<tagname>`:

```rb
git "apt-cookbook" do
  repository "https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/apt"
  revision "refs/tags/v2.9.2"
  action :sync
end
```

Comment: I'm very sure that doesn't matter. Git's tags are (AFAIK) always in `refs/tags/*`. It's not about the path in the Git server's web interface etc. The repo is cloned from the URL in `repository`, afterwards the `revision` is checked out.

Comment: No, that does not matter. Try e.g. the code [here](https://gist.github.com/StephenKing/c5bc5494e3e68c6e0e8b).

Comment: My memory should be faulty in this case :) sorry

Comment: If there is both a tag and a branch with the same name, I think the branch wins.

Comment: @StephenKing Thank you very much. `refs/tags/<tagname>` solved the issues I'm having!